# Регулярка |(.*)|Uis

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Есть регулярка, которая прекрасно ищет то, что между тегами `|<span class="ip">(.*)</span>|Uis`, но вместе с этим еще нужно спарсить название картинки, которое записано так:

```
<img src="/images/flags/ro.gif" alt="" class="item_16x11"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Что-то, походу, никто не знает. :(

В общем, вот так, вроде, работает:

```
|<img src="/images/flags/(.*).gif" alt="" class="item_16x11"/>(.*)<span class="ip">(.*)</span><span class="port">:(.*)</span>|Uis
```